# Typescript picking wrong type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, victory-charts

I am sorry for maybe dull question but I am learning typescript and hit to situation I can not get over.

I use [Victory](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/) charts where component accepts to pass data of type `DomainPropType`. So I downloaded and installed [@types/victory](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/victory) to use this type.

Since that, it is possible to pass the data to the component.

But ...

```
// unimportant code was striped out

import { DomainPropType } from 'victory';

class Charts extends Component<Props, State> {
    private entireDomain: DomainPropType;

    public constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);

        this.entireDomain = this.getEntireDomain();
        console.log(this.entireDomain);    // <= got {x:[82800000, 1206000000] ,y: [0, 1]}
        console.log(this.entireDomain.x);  // <= got 'Property 'x' does not exist on type 'DomainPropType'.
    }


    public getEntireDomain(): DomainPropType {
        const xValues = this.entireDataSet.map((item: DataSetItem) => item.x);
        const yValues = this.entireDataSet.map((item: DataSetItem) => item.y);

        return {
            x: [xValues[0].valueOf(), xValues[xValues.length - 1].valueOf()],
            y: [Math.min(...yValues), Math.max(...yValues)]
        };
    }
}
```

In the first console.log it is clear to see that `entireDomain` is object with key `x`. So why in the second console.log typeScript throws following error?

```
Property 'x' does not exist on type 'DomainPropType'.
Property 'x' does not exist on type '[number, number]'.
```

Ok it also says `[number, number]`. However this is how the type looks like:

[image]

If I understand correctly... DomainPropType can be also of type `{ x?: DomainTuple; y: DomainTuple; }`. Then why typeScript chose the wrong one for validation? Please someone explain to me.

Comment: typescript doesn't know what type out of 3 will be, so it check all of them for your action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a type to a function argument/constructor, typescript assumes that somewhere else in your code, someone might call that function/constructor with those arguments.

So even if you only use your class once, and in that specific case you pass an object with `x` and `y` properties, it's still possible that later on you also use the class and use the `[number, number]` or `[Date, Date]` formats.

To avoid this, you have 2 options:

1. Don't use `DomainPropType` as the argument type but instead only use the specific type you actually want to use.
2. In your constructor, correctly handle the `[number, number]` and `[Date, Date]` cases.

If you never intend to call this object with `[Date, Date]` or `[number, number]`, going for option 1 is probably the easiest.

Example of a more specific type that I think will work for your case:

```
type MyDomainPropType = {
   x: DomainTuple,
   y?: DomainTuple
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It is true I never intend to use object with `[Date, Date]` or `[number, number]` however I need to have type `DomainPropType`. Otherwise I get error here `<VictoryChart domain={this.entireDomain} />` This component requires the type.

Comment: @TomášVavřinka: that component requires one of the 3 or 4 types. If you give it a more specific type, it will still work. This is similar to when you have a function argument that's `string | number`. If you give it just a number, it will still work.

Comment: Lets an edit, try that out. It should work for your case. It just forced your component to just always use that 1 variant.

Comment: Yes! After my countless attempts this finally works. Many thanks.

Comment: @TomášVavřinka, awesome! Good luck =)

Answer (score 0):

You could cast your array like that :

```
return {
            x: [xValues[0].valueOf(), xValues[xValues.length - 1].valueOf()],
            y: [Math.min(...yValues), Math.max(...yValues)]
        } as DomainPropType;
```

Maybe your error is linked to the nullable x or y you can see in your screenshot.

Comment: This is as bad as just using `any`. This hides the underlying problem.

Comment: Well if you really want to solve this the right way, you would have to write an interface that extends DomainProType, But there is no point on doing that since you are explicitly writing the shape of your object. Maybe just adding the questionmark in the returned object works ?

Comment: I kinda left this in my own answer, but the right way is to use a more explicit type or handle the other 2/3 cases. Typescript complains because the type is not specific enough and someone can subclass this file and return something else from `getEntireDomain`.

Comment: What you suggest unfortunately makes no difference. But how can I explicit say which one of the types I use?